# If element is present with a specific class and data-attribute "position x", append that element to a list of items after "position x"

Tags: jquery

If an element thas has class `itemToAppend` is present and has a specific data-attribute "position", `data-position="2"`, append that element to list of items after position `2`.

Here is what I would like to achieve, let's say we have:

```
<div class="itemToAppend" data-position="2">My Item</div>
```

My `itemToAppend` is present so append that element after my second `<li>`

```
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>
    <div class="itemToAppend" data-position="2">My Item</div>
  </li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a simple way to do this with jquery?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use insertAfter to insert the desired element after the element with an n index.
You check the data-position to get the desired location. You use :eq selector to insert the element after the element with that position.

https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
let itemPosition = parseInt($(".itemToAppend").attr("data-position"));
$(".itemToAppend").insertAfter("ul li:eq("+itemPosition+")");
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, this what I wanted to achieve. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `insertAfter`

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("button").click(function() { 
    $("li").has(".itemToAppend").remove();
    $(`<li><div class="itemToAppend" data-position="2">My Item</div>
  </li>`).insertAfter(`ul li:nth-child(${$('#test').val()})`); 
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>  
  <li>List 5</li>
  <li>List 6</li>
</ul>

<input id="test" type="number" value="1"/>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is not exactly what I would like to achieve.
`<div class="itemToAppend" data-position="2">My Item</div>` is already there in my web page. What I would like to do is that it will insert to another `div` at `position = 2`. Also I didn't mention that `data-position=""` can change, so if I have `data-position="3"` it will insert at `position = 3`

What do you think?